# Javascript Why when i use drawImage in `mousemove` i get bad image?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to draw a image when action mousemove, but when i use drawImage in `mousemove` i get bad image (see right image):

[image]

Why the image is drawn badly when action `mousemove`?

P.S.: i would like draw right image with quality left image;

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_test');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img_test__src = 'http://image.prntscr.com/image/8233c5a42e7e4b40a19c64d8e9b892ee.png';

var img = new Image();
img.src = img_test__src;
img.onload = function() {
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.drawImage(img, 100, 100, 71, 71);
  context.closePath();
  context.restore();
};

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = img_test__src;
  img.onload = function() {
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.drawImage(img, 200, 100, 71, 71);
    context.closePath();
    context.restore();
  };
});
```

```css
#canvas_test {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas_test" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Noooo..... you are loading the image for each mouse event.. Load it only once, have you not noticed how slow it is.

Comment: ditto @Blindman67's comment & answer + a useless save/restore all properties of the context + a useless beginPath at this frame rate! I hope my mouse wont enter your canvas ever for the sake of my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Never render inside a IO event

You should never render in an event if at all possible. The frequency and timing is out of your control and it can produce all sorts of problems, especially when you start to have many of these things going on.

Use `requestAnimationFrame` even if it is just for one frame. This will ensure that the image is drawn correctly and in sync with any other animations or visual updates that are happening.

**DONT LOAD IMAGES over and over!!!**

I had to give an answer as you are also loading the image in the event.

Every mouse move, maybe some 100 or more a second you create a new image and wait for it to load. You should have noticed how the page lags at times.

Load the image once.

**Example**

I am assuming you want a mouse over FX

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_test');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img_test__src = 'http://image.prntscr.com/image/8233c5a42e7e4b40a19c64d8e9b892ee.png';

var img = new Image();
img.src = img_test__src;
img.onload = drawImg;
var mouseOver = false;
function drawImg(){
   if(img.complete){ // has image loaded
       context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
       context.globalAlpha = mouseOver ? 1 : 0.5;
       context.drawImage(img,0,0);
       context.globalAlpha = 1;
   }
}
canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', function(evt) {
   mouseOver = true;
   requestAnimationFrame(drawImg);
});
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', function(evt) {
   mouseOver = false;
   requestAnimationFrame(drawImg);
});
```

```css
#canvas_test {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
   
<canvas id="canvas_test" width="65" height="65"></canvas>
```

Comment: you are right! thanks a lot and +1 for you because of this.

Answer (score 3):

You draw the image multiple times at once. So it overlaps and you see that effect. Change `mousemove` to `mouseenter` and it will work, when you first enter. If you enter again you even more see an artifact because of alpha overlap on multiple draws.

Clear the canvas area before draw to ommit this, if you have to use `mousemove` or other events that fire more than once.

https://jsfiddle.net/uy55o8v5/

Comment: This is correct. The browser fires "mousemove" very, very often when the mouse is moving; basically it sends as many events as it can. You can clearly see the effect if the "click" event is used instead.

Comment: It's still an overkill to create a new image + load an image at each of this event + this solution won't work if the canvas takes the whole screen (there would be only one mouseenter)

Comment: Brain thanks for help, +1 for you, i mark other answer becouse he use `requestAnimationFrame`